# $\|P\|_2 \ge1$ if and only if $P$ is an orthogonal projector.

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Let $P$ be a nonzero projector.

$\|P\|_2 \geq 1$ with equality iff $P$ is an orthogonal projector.

I already proved $(\Leftarrow)$ way.

However, It is a sticking point to solve $(\Rightarrow$)

I saw that there is a [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4466377/lvert-p-rvert-2-1-iff-p-is-an-orthogonal-projector-proof), but I don't undertstand with this post, since it is about equality, but I want to solve this with inequality.

I tried $P^2=P$, since $P$ is a projector, and doing some inequality but it doesn't work.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1109755/81360)

Comment: Notation: use `\|P\|` for better spacing between norm bars: $\|P\|$ vs. $||P||$.

Comment: you can streamline the argument by using an inequality of Schur i.e. if $P$ has rank $r$, it is diagonalizable with eigenvalues of 0 and 1 and $\big \Vert P\big \Vert_2\ = 1 \implies r = \big \Vert P\big \Vert_2^2\cdot r  \geq \big \Vert P\big \Vert_F^2\geq \sum_{k=1}^n \vert \lambda_k\vert^2 = r$  -- is met with equality so $P$ is normal, i.e. unitarily diagonalizable with real spectrum, hence Hermitian, i.e. an orthogonal projector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally true that for a non-zero projector $P$, $\|P\|_2 \geq 1$. This can be seen, for instance, by noting that for any non-zero vector $x$ in the image of $P$, we have $Px = x$, hence
$$
\|x\| = \|Px\| \leq \|P\|_2 \|x\| \implies \|P\|_2 \geq 1.
$$
As the linked post shows, $\|P\|_2 = 1$ if and only if $P$ is an orthogonal projection. For all other cases, we can conclude that $\|P\|_2 > 1$ using the above observation.

Comment: I read your answer several times. Overall, I understood ∥P∥2=1
  if and only if P
 is an orthogonal projection, but how can I show that $\|P\|_2 > 1$ implies $P$ is orthogonal projector? Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: Come to think about it, "$\|P\|_2 \geq 1$ iff $P$ is an orthogonal projection" is weird, because $\|P\|_2 = 1$ iff $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: @JAEMTO Your comment is confusing. The goal here is to conclude that $\|P\|_2 > 1$ implies that $P$ is **not** an orthogonal projector. Also, I never say that "$\|P\|_2 \geq 1$ iff $P$ is an orthogonal projection." In any case, maybe the following explanation will help: in general, it is true (for a non-zero projector $P$) that either $\|P\|_2 = 1$ or $\|P\|_2 > 1$ (i.e. $\|P\|_2 \geq 1$). If $P$ is not orthogonal, then it cannot be true that $\|P\|_2 = 1$, so it must be true that $\|P\|_2 > 1$.

Comment: @JAEMTO I assumed that your title was meant to be a shortening of the correct statement from your question, "$\|P\|_2 \geq 1$ **with equality iff** $P$ is an orthogonal projector." Your title as it currently stands is an incorrect statement.